# Change Series of Numbers to List, python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have been given a series of numbers I would like to take and put into a python list or tuple as comma separated numbers. I've been digging around on stacked, but maybe I can't find the correct way to phrase my question because I keep finding ways to conver tuples to lists and vice versa.

This is what I have. I received an email with a list series of numbers like so (but several hundred more):

```
417985
417986
417987
417988
417989
417990
```

I will use the numbers to query from a database, so:

```
NUMBER in (417985,417986,417987,417988,417989,417990)
```

Is there any way in python to convert that series of numbers so that I canget the comma separated values in the query? FYI, I do a lot of python, so that's where I am comforable, however any other method I would be interested to hear.

Comment: Presumably you are talking about a SQL query?

Comment: Is the `'NUMBER in (%s)' % ','.join(list_with_your_numbers)` or something similiar is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use these numbers in a SQL query, you need to generate *SQL parameters* rather than build a query string.

You'd read your lines and turn this into a sequence (a list will do) of integers:

```
numbers = [int(line) for line in email_lines]
```

You then generate a query with enough placeholders for each of those values:

```
statement = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE NUMBER IN ({0})".format(
    ', '.join(['?' * len(numbers)]))
```

where I assume that the database connector you are using uses `?` as the SQL parameter placeholder; it could also be `%s`.

Now you can ask the database for matching rows:

```
cursor.execute(statement, numbers)
```

By using SQL parameters you get a few things for free:

- Proper quoting and escaping of the values. Less important here because you are already converting everything to integers, but it is a good practice to not escape and quote values yourself; you will almost certainly miss something.
- Reuse of cached query plans; the database only has to parse the `statement` query once and can reuse the result for subsequent queries.

If you wanted to copy and paste those numbers, type this:

```
email_lines = """\
<paste your lines with numbers>
""".splitlines()
```

then apply the first line from my answer to the result.

Comment: Thanks Martijn! Maybe I need to clarify a little more. My thought was to just copy the series of numbers into python shell and just parse each one out so that I can get a list or tuple. I can then copy and paste the list into the program I am using for the query. My final query will be as I mentioned in the original question, so I just want to have each number separated by a comma wrapped in a lsit container that I can copy and paste.

Comment: @Mike: if you just wanted to copy and paste, I gave you a way to do so. That way you get a list of strings, one string per line you pasted. The `[int(line) for line in email_lines]` list comprehension will then give you a list of integers.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. It took me a few minutes to figure out how this works. Works like a charm now. Thatnks for the final edit to include the email_lines variable.

Answer (score 1):

Is this maybe  what  you want?

```
raw = """417985
417986
417987
417988
417989
417990"""

numbers = [int(n) for n in raw.split()]

>> numbers_int
[417985, 417986, 417987, 417988, 417989, 417990]
```

Or if you want to construct a string

```
numbers_str = [n for n in raw.split()]
>> ",".join(numbers_str)
'417985,417986,417987,417988,417989,417990'
```

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I tried this one out too and again, I got soemthing that would work as well.